# IOS/Objective-C: Set NSItemProvider

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, foundation

How would I render the following in Swift into Objective-C?

```
let vCardActivity = NSItemProvider(item: vCardData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeVCard as String)
```

Can't find this in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsitemprovider?language=objc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Objective-C is starting to get rusty, and I've never used an `NSItemProvider` before, but it should be something like:

```
NSItemProvider* vCardActivity = 
  [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem: vCardData 
  typeIdentifier: (NSString *) kUTTypeVCard];
```

Comment: throws 'use of undeclared identifier kUTTypeVCard' error

Comment: Got rid of that error by importing mobilecoreservices.  Now throws warning incompatible pointer types sending const CFString to parameter of type NSString

Comment: You can ignore that warning or fix it with a cast. It's harmless.

Comment: Marking correct.  However, my VCard string still not being recognized in activityviewcontroller.  My code is vCardString= [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem: vCardData typeIdentifier: kUTTypeVCard];
    NSLog(@"vCardString%@",vCardString);
    NSArray *activityItems = @[text,vCardString];  Appears blank in email/text etc. and logs as BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Colin
TEL:
URL:http://(null)
END:VCARD

Comment: Is there a way to put the as String in there?  That may be why it is not recognizing string

Comment: "as String" is Swift syntax. I'll edit my answer to do a cast in Objective-C

Comment: Ok!  That got rid of warning.  Vcard still isn't displaying in activityviewcontroller but at least I know that is not issue.

Comment: To cast to a different type in Objective-C, put the new type in parentheses before the expression you want to cast, as in my edited answer.